# Laravel: file_get_contents not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am learning in Laravel and I got a strange error with `Laravel 5.4` and `XAMPP 5.6.23`.
Let say I have a Laravel app with APIController and UserController.
In APIController.index() function:

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::all();
    return response()->json($users);
}
```

In UserController.index() function:

```
public function index()
{
    $url = route("api.index");
    $content = @file_get_contents($url);
    dd($content);
}
```

Note `route("api.index")` `return "http://localhost:8000/api"`, and is mapping to the APIController.index() function.
In php.ini I have "allow_url_fopen" = On. The problem is file_get_contents() always exceed maximum time.  When I replace $url = "`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments`", however, it works. I dont know what's wrong cuz Laravel doesnt show me any error rather than Maximum time exceeded. Any one can help? Thank you!

Comment: Can you try File::get($filename) as explained here, http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/126/getting-the-contents

Comment: @manian Why would that help him? `File::get()` just does `return file_get_contents()`.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, the same issue happened to me few months back & File::get() helped me fix the issue. I tried to recall the exact cause of my issue at that time but I could not recall yet(bad memory). I posted this link from my references.

Comment: If you're planning to reuse the controller logic, then doing it this way is absurd. You can directly call other controller methods in laravel. This might help you with reusing the api method for web.

Comment: @manian I used File::get(), but it didnt work with file that retrieve from url. I tried File::getRemote(), but it said "Method getRemote does not exist." Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After google for many times, my answer for this is : I cant read API data that come from the same project as where the controller come. I must write the function read API in jquery (in view not controller). Sadly,tho

Answer (score 0):

You can access `http://localhost:8000/` from your pc (outside of XAMPP).
But, you need to check what happens to access `http://localhost:8000/` from inside of XAMPP where PHP is running.

1. Login to XAMPP server
2. Try `$ curl -i http://localhost:8000`

My guess:

1. :8000 is not open.
2. You may need to change domain or port or path.